# How to go back to parent category link from single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to display a link to go back to the parent category of the product if there is one in `woocommerce`, otherwise i would like the link to return to the main shop page.

I cant find how to do this in WordPress, any help will be appreciated to help me solve this.

Comment: rude people minus here, even I put plus still -1 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the category id by using bellow code and then add if condition to show the like

```
$product_category = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
```

Comment: Got it working :) Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction!